# tkinter showinfo python 3

Tags: tkinter, messagebox, python-3.4

I am trying to show an info window by using

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("info", "message")
```

However, I am getting error while using `from tkinter import *`

The problem is solve if I also have `import tkinter.messagebox`

So I am confused. Isn't `from tkinter import *` is supposed to import everything inside `tkinter`?

Answer (score 6):

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

root.title("test")
root.geometry("300x300")

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = " exit " , width=2, command=exit)
button1.grid(padx=110, pady=80)

def dialog():
    var = messagebox.showinfo("test" , "hoi, dit is een test als je dit leest is het gelukt")
button2 = Button(app, text = " uitleg " , width=4, command=dialog)
button2.grid()


root.mainloop(3)
```

you just import messagebox from tkinter and you do messagebox.(for example)showinfo("test" , "blablablabla")

Answer (score 5):

`from tkinter import *` will load Tkinter's `__init__.py` which doesn't include messagebox, so to solve it we do `import tkinter.messagebox` which loads messagebox's `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `from module import x` format, you don't prefix the imported resources with the module. So try

```
messagebox.showinfo("info", "message")
```

If you import like this: `import tkinter.messagebox` you reference it with the module, which is why you don't get an error in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Can also try this method to access the `messagebox` method

```
import tkinter as tk

tk.messagebox.showinfo("info name","This is a Test")
```